# php Wikipedia API JSON get page ID

Tags: php, api, wikipedia

I want to get some wikipedia information using their api but how would I get the page id? Because it is in the JSON array.

```
echo $json["query"]["pages"][HERE_IS_THE_PAGE_ID]["pageid"];
```

Comment: What's the json like?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=ICANN&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to [loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) through the "pages" array.

```
foreach ($json["query"]["pages"] as $page_id => $this_page) {
    echo $page_id;
    // OR
    echo $this_page['pageid'];
}
```

If you're certain that the data only contains one page, you could just access the array [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
$page_id = key($json["query"]["pages"]);
```

[Here's an example.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a362fdf0e2e62e56385abbb057117ab861ebb842)

Or use [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) or [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to access the (first) page array:

```
$this_page = current($data["Something is wrong"]["pages"]);
$page_id=$this_page["pageid"];
```

[Here's an example.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8574e81f76dd09873a7a9d4c7b913777433e7b83)

Comment: I'm stupid though, never thought about accessing the pages key. Thank you :)